# Right-trimming text files

Tags: vba, vbscript

1. below vbscript code took me 3hours just to complete trimming whitespaces of a 24MB file any tips to speed up the process below?

> ```
> dim filename, path \'variables
>      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>      Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
>      strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
>      filename = replace(strFolder,"jobs\SCRIPTS","shared\file") & "\DCS.txt"
>      converter(filename)
>      objFile.Close
>      function converter(filename)
>      Const ForReading = 1
>      Const ForWriting = 2
>      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>      PATH = filename
>      Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(PATH, ForReading)
>      Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
>         strLine = objFile.Readline
>         strLine = Trim(strLine)
>         If Len(strLine)  0 Then
>             strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbcrlf
>         End If
>      Loop
>      objFile.Close
>      Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(PATH, ForWriting)
>      objFile.Write strNewContents
>      objFile.Close
>      msgbox "done trim on " & filename
>      end function
> ```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly. Please be more descriptive in the question body as well. What made you write this code? What does your input look like?

Comment: I rarely say this, but you should consider the `tr` command line tool, it should be way faster than this.

Comment: Or even this single-line in PowerShell: `(gc $filename)| % {$_.trim()} | sc $filename`

Comment: i have no basic knowledge on powershell. But will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @TediCarandang You can also use the powershell command into a batch file !

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to be writing VBScript or WSScript files then you should be using [VBEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/).

[image: Intellisense Image]

[image: VBEdit Image]

Allow it is not required you should still capitalize End, Function and Sub.

Wrapping each tasks in it's own Sub or Function will make it easier to read, debug and modify your code.

A Function that does not return a value should be a Sub.

Avoid editing text files line by line.  It is much more efficient to split the text into an array of lines, edit each element of the array, and then join the output.

### Refactored Code

This code takes less than 1 second to trim each line of a 27 MB text file.

```
Dim FullFileName
FullFileName = GetSharedFileName

If FileSystemObject.FileExists(FullFileName) Then
    TrimFileContents FullFileName
    MsgBox "Done"
Else
    MsgBox "File not found: " & FullFileName
End If


Sub TrimFileContents(FullFileName)
    Dim Lines
    Lines = GetTextFileLines(FullFileName)
    
    Dim n

    For n = 0 To UBound(Lines)
        Lines(n) = Trim(Lines(n))
    Next
    
    OverWriteTextFile FullFileName, Join(Lines, vbNewLine)
End Sub

Function GetSharedFileName
    GetSharedFileName = Replace(GetParentFolderName,"jobs\SCRIPTS","shared\file") & "\DCS.txt"
End Function

Function FileSystemObject
    Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End Function


Function GetParentFolderName

    GetParentFolderName = FileSystemObject.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.Path

End Function

Function GetTextFileLines(FullFileName)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim Text
    With FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(FullFileName, ForReading)
        Text = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
    
    If InStr(Text, vbNewLine) = 0 Then
        GetTextFileLines = Split(Text, vbLf)
    Else
        GetTextFileLines = Split(Text, vbNewLine)
    End If

End Function

Sub OverWriteTextFile(FullFileName, Text)
    Const ForWriting = 2

    With FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(FullFileName, ForWriting)
        .Write Text
        .Close
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code tips. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Being on Linux I can't run your code right now but here is an idea.

I think the string concatenation must be *very* inefficient:

```
strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbcrlf
```

What you are doing:

- read the source file line by line
- then concatenate to a big string
- write the string in one go at the end

What I think you should be doing:

- open the source file for reading, and the target file for writing
- read the source file line by line
- at each iteration, write a trimmed line to the target file
- then close both files at the end

That's it, read and write at the same time, that should solve your performance problem.

A better alternative to the string concatenation would otherwise be the stringbuilder class if available in VBA (I don't think so). I agree with the suggestion that Powershell would be a better option. Many things can be done with one-liners.

Comment: will try your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As @HackSlash proposed to you in the comment : a single-line in Powershell

`(gc $filename)| % {$_.trim()} | sc $filename`

You can use the powershell command into a batch file :

Just save this code below in your notepad or notepad++ and save it as : `Trim_File.bat` and drag and drop any file in order to trim it !

---

```bat
@echo off
Color 0A & Mode 80,4
Title Trimming Text files with Powershell and Batch by Hackoo 2020
Set "InputFile=%~1"
If "%InputFile%" EQU "" Goto :Help
Set "OutPutFile=%~dpn1_Trimmed.txt"
echo(
echo(    Please wait a while ... Trimming this file "%~nx1"
REM ----------------------------------------------------------
Powershell ^
(GC '"%InputFile%"'^) ^| %% {$_.trim()} ^| SC '"%OutPutFile%"' 
REM ----------------------------------------------------------
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & Exit
REM ----------------------------------------------------------
:Help
Color 0C
echo(
echo(              You should drag and drop a file over, 
echo(              this script "%~nx0" in order to trim it !
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak>nul
Exit /B
REM ----------------------------------------------------------
```